# How many years after MSc graduation, am I able with possibilities to be accepted from a PhD program?

Tags: phd, rejection, graduation

I graduated one year ago and still haven't found a PhD after many applications. In two of these I was ranked at 3rd and 2nd positions accordingly, but I regard that even though has been passed one year from my graduation, I should keep going.
What do you think?

Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

In many places you have a chance until you die, so don't lose heart.

But you might want to evaluate why you haven't been accepted. For many people it is just too few applications. For others it is only applying for positions in a very narrow range of institutions, such as "top 20 in the field". And there might be ways you can improve your application materials as well, including letters of recommendation and your statement of purpose.

But a year is really nothing.

Don't lose contact with those that can support your candidacy. After ten years, it will be much harder if no one in academia remembers you.

Comment: I was searching for both famous and non-famous universities-instututions. I have a BSc in geology with grade 6.91 and an MSc in seismology in which field I am interested on with grade 8.48. I have also a 2month internship experience and 14 months research experience before MSc graduation. I am also worried if the problem is on my grades.